# CodeIgniter, upload and config

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'd like to config my upload using /config/upload.php. However, some of my config items will vary depending on the situation. In most cases, the upload directory is dynamically set (e.g. it incorporates the user's id, uses a random folder, etc.). Sometimes, the type of files that can be uploaded will be different (e.g. only photos in one case, only videos in another case).

Can I put the general config items in /config/upload.php and add/override certain things later? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller that you are using to upload you just need to redefine the options for the upload library and initialize them again.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

// Alternately you can set preferences by calling the initialize function. Useful if you auto-load the class:
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

You will lose all your predefined config items I'm pretty sure so you'll need to redo those

**UPDATE**

After looking into this a little more this may be possible.  If you look at the `Upload` library there are functions inside where you can `set` some of the variables.  There aren't `set` functions for all and they may not all be a `set` function that you can use.  So you could do something like this.

```
$this->load->library("Upload"); // loads upload library with predefined config items in config/upload.php

//to change upload path
$this->upload->set_upload_path("new location");
//CANNOT DO THIS BECAUSE ITS USED IN do_upload function you would need to extend the upload library and create your own set function.
$this->upload->set_filename("new filename");

$this->upload->do_upload();
```

Others that look like can be used to set values

```
set_max_filesize
set_max_filename
set_max_width
set_max_height
set_allowed_types
```

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I just want to override certain config values. If I am going to do this each time I upload, then there is no point in having /config/upload.php.

Comment: @Henesnarfel That worked great. Thank you :) I used the abmove method to redefine the allowed file types.

Comment: @Henesnarfel: If I use this: $this->upload->set_upload_path("new location"); do I also need to initialize the library again?

Comment: @Lykos no you should not have to.  You would make that call after the initialization to change a default value.  All those functions do is change the values after you've initialized.  So if you wanted to upload multiple files you could potentially change the `upload_path` for each one by using a `foreach` and calling `set_upload_path` for each one without having to initialize each time.  I haven't done this but I think that should work that way.